# ColumnLayout items size proportions

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have QML `Item` with one `ListView` (bottom part of `Item`) and one `GridView` (upper part of `Item`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item
{
    width: 768
    height: 512


    ColumnLayout
    {
        id: ueCentralWidget

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.fill: parent

        spacing: 8

        Rectangle
        {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            border.color: "#4682b4"
            radius: 16

            gradient: Gradient
            {
                GradientStop
                {
                    position: 0
                    color: "#ffffff"
                }   // GradientStop

                GradientStop
                {
                    position: 1
                    color: "#000000"
                }   // GradientStop
            }   // Gradient

            ColumnLayout
            {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                anchors.fill: parent

                UeProductSelector
                {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.margins: 8

                    antialiasing: true
                    clip: true
                }   // UeProductSelector

                UeCategorySelector
                {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.margins: 8

                    antialiasing: true
                    clip:true
                }   // UeCategorySelector
            }   // ColumnLayout
        }   // Rectangle
    }   // ColumnLayout
}
```

I want to lower `ListView` occupy **1/3** of `Item` size and `GridView` occupy **2/3** of `Item` size., Adding task screenshot:
[image: Situation screenshot]
How do I achieve such task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fillWidth` and `fillHeight` on all `Item`s of my `Layout` was the problem. Setting the `preferredHeight` to `parent.height/3` and leaving  the other with `fillHeigh` solved the issue for me.

Here is the working code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Item
{
    width: 768
    height: 512


    ColumnLayout
    {
        id: ueCentralWidget

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.fill: parent

        spacing: 8

        Rectangle
        {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            border.color: "#4682b4"
            radius: 16

            gradient: Gradient
            {
                GradientStop
                {
                    position: 0
                    color: "#ffffff"
                }   // GradientStop

                GradientStop
                {
                    position: 1
                    color: "#000000"
                }   // GradientStop
            }   // Gradient

            ColumnLayout
            {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                anchors.fill: parent

                UeProductSelector
                {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.margins: 8

                    antialiasing: true
                    clip: true
                }   // UeProductSelector

                UeCategorySelector
                {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height/3
                    Layout.margins: 8

                    antialiasing: true
                    clip:true
                }   // UeCategorySelector
            }   // ColumnLayout
        }   // Rectangle
    }   // ColumnLayout
}
```